# apache server running but django site not loading (used wsgi)

Tags: python, django, apache, wsgi

I'm using AWS EC2 ubuntu 18.04 instance running apache2 server to load my django site using wsgi.
I've managed to get apache server running but when I try to open the page using my ip on browser, is says the site couldn't be loaded. The server is listening on port 80. I'm using a virtualenv to run django project. DaemonProcess is used to run venv as python home.

The `/etc/apache2/sites-available/django.conf` file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    LogLevel error
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /static /project/src/static
    <Directory /project/src/static>
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    Alias /media /project/src/media
    <Directory /project/src/media>
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /project/src/project>
            <Files wsgi.py>
                    Require all granted
            </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIScriptAlias / /project/src/project/wsgi.py
    WSGIDaemonProcess shout_app python-path=/project/src python-home=/project/venv
    WSGIProcessGroup shout_app

</VirtualHost>
```

The `/var/apache2/error.log` file after restarting apache and loading ip:

```
[Sun Jun 14 21:07:30.830952 2020] [suexec:notice] [pid 16647:tid 139870270000064] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/lib/apache2/suexec)
[Sun Jun 14 21:07:30.840208 2020] [:notice] [pid 16663:tid 139870270000064] mod_ruid2/0.9.8 enabled
[Sun Jun 14 21:07:30.843684 2020] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 16663:tid 139870270000064] AH00489: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.1.1 configured -- resuming normal operat$
[Sun Jun 14 21:07:30.843701 2020] [core:notice] [pid 16663:tid 139870270000064] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

The `wsgi.py` file:

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'project.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Can anyone suggest a solution? Where should I be looking specifically for the issue?

Comment: Could you answer the question, in case you figured out the fix yourself.